# Resizing div depending on the screen size

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

I have trouble with depending on resizing screen, there is header which include a few divs. Left div - with fixed width in 464px, top div - fixed width 500px, bottom div - should resize depending on screen size and divs inside bottom should be sticky, social - to the left, apps - to the right.
Maybe I should use some mixins to solve this problem?

Jade:

```
div.wrap
 div.left
 div.top
 div.bottom
  div.social
  div.input
  div.apps
```

Css:

```
.wrap{width: 100%; height: 500px}
.left{width: 464px; height: 100%; float: left}
.top{width: 500px; height: 100px; float: left}
.bottom{height: 300px; width: ???;}
.social{float: left}
.apps{float: right}
```

Comment: Why you tagged `JavaScript`?

Comment: @MehdiDehghani maybe there is some solution in js

Comment: `percentage` width. doesn't work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to resize your div according on screen size, you should not use fixed width or should not take width in pixel, take width in 100%;